Context menu items : greyed out vs. always available (clickable items that may show an explanation why they can't be executed)
The question/debate is about the context menu items :

should I allow all commands at any time, then, when a user selects an action, either perform it or explain why it cannot be done (like missing access rights)
should I grey out items that cannot be executed in the context.

To make it clear : this is not about greyed-out vs. invisible items; this would be a later choice given the state of the command is known; this question is about showing selectable menu items vs greyed-out-or-invisible menu items and the cost of doing so.
Context :

a document management webapp that has an explorer-like user interface (with folders, too)
all data is persisted in a database back-end
the user can display a context menu (about 30-40 commands in it) over a selection of documents and/or folders; the size of the selection is not limited and can be easily beyond 100 items
there is an access rights model that handles access rights at document level for users and groups (for instance I may not have been assigned directly a specific right on a specific document, but because one of the groups I'm member of has it then I have it)
folders and documents have a persistent state (saved in the database)
folders and documents also have a transient state (which obviously does not 'live' past system restarts)
the system may handle up to 100M documents (although probably an average value would be between 100K - 500K documents)

Given the context...

The main disadvantage of the first approach seems to be that users can execute commands that may have nothing to do with the selection... but at least they end up with a message saying so.
The main disadvantage of the second approach is that given N commands and a selection of M items that means that some N*M checks have to be performed (obviously depending on the algorithm used), most involving database access with a non-negligeable cost.

Caching in memory doesn't seem a very efficient approach since the different users are unlikely to request data on the same items and cache maintenance (expiration and eviction may create additional cost with little value)
Any thoughts on this matter are highly appreciated. I'm quite sure a definitive solution does not exist, but I think based on others' experience one may find a solution appropriate to their own problem.

This question is similar to: Greyed-Out vs Invisible. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Danielillo: I do not think it's similar because the question you suggested deals with how to handle items that are not available but do not provide feedback. Please see the title; this is a different scenario. Thank you.

Similar question 1, Similar question 2, etc. Please, use the search field.

@Danielillo This is not about greyed-out vs invisible. It's a totally different question. Please read my question and understand it first.

'Showing Selectable vs greyed out or invisible'. Not sure why you are questioning displaying selectable items in a menu. And then the other part is greyed out vs invisible, which has been discussed in the other similar questions. Please explain how this is different.

"when a user selects an action, either perform it or explain why it cannot be done" – this is a wrong approach and goes against user's conscious decision making. The user was not informed before making the decision. Hiding information and embarrassing the user by displaying error messages is not the way to go.

@Ren : I somehow agree, but how can I inform him before making a decision if the command is greyed-out ?

It can simply be explained on the side of the item in parenthesis. e.g. [Option (*Admin access only)]. But it brings us back to the same question – if access is denied, why even display.

You could use different colors to show unavailable actions like greying out and when the user hovers over, you can show a tooltip that says example ‘Missing Access Rights’.

Indeed, but this approach does not 'solve' the problem of deciding when it should change color, so not exactly a solution.

I often object to disabling fields, links, buttons etc. I rather leave things enabled so that users can discover for themselves what works and what doesn't and why.
In your case: don't gray out the unavailable items and leave them enabled (clickable/interactive). To let users know in advance that it's not available, add that to the label: Delete (not available). People can either understand or accept that the action is not available or they don't and click on it anyway, then show a message why it isn't available.
If the (unavailable) addition makes the labels too long it is also possible to group unavailable items:
Rename
Move
-- unavailable actions --
Delete

Downside is that the order of items is not consistent, but if that is a real problem is something to observe.

thank you for your answer; in my case, unfortunately, the additional text is not an option, as the menu has a mix of icons and icon+text items, a bit like the windows explorer menu that has the copy/paste icons on top. Maybe I can reconfigure the menu items so that the icon-only items are never disabled; I'll look into this possibility.

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

@Danielillo : it's an interesting approach, but I wouldn't upvote yet... what's wrong with thanking someone for taking the time to read and answer ? Is it against policy ?

Because in SE the way to thank is by upvoting the effort and dedication in preparing a response. Visit the Help Center.

@Danielillo This is a better link: https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. But the comment wasn't just "thank you" but also some feedback, there's nothing wrong with that.

@stefanu Please feel free to comment if you have more feedback or upvote the answer if you found the answer helpful enough. If it did answer your question somehow, please accept it as the answer.
